# vlookup / index nested function?

Tags: excel, vlookup

[image: example]

I am needing to lookup and qualify two cells to return the result of a third cell in the same row, then either add or count those returned values per location.

possible vlookup I:I="KC" then qualify each corresponding KC with column J for a "Y" or "N" value. If "Y", then the corresponding H column "$xxx" and add up all prices that have locations with KC and Deposit "Y".

I've tried Vlookup, but I am not good at nesting to qualify multiple criteria.

Comment: You want `SUMIFS`.

Comment: Also are you using `Excel` or `Google-Sheets` both platforms are not same, even though if your query it can be solved using the said function as mentioned above by @BigBen Sir, ^^^ however from the screenshot it seems you're using GS

Comment: All of which is correct - answer fixed what I needed. Thanks all!

Answer (score 0):

```
=SUMIFS(H:H,I:I,"=KC",J:J,"=Y")
```

Comment: Note that `"=KC"` and `"=Y"` can be simplified by dropping the `=`.